# Do something when a Zurb-reveal.js modal dialog is closed

Tags: javascript, html, zurb-foundation

I have a big list of items and i need to set a modal box to each of these items.

The problem is: i'm creating a lots of modal boxes in the DOM and i only want 1 for every items.

I'm creating the modal HTML everytime that the user click on one item and i put it in the body.
But now i need to remove the modal from the DOM (body) when this is closed by the user.

**It's possible to trigger a function when the modal box is closed?**

Comment: ([reveal.js is something else](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation/flexibility is scant at best for this library; might want to use a different dialog plugin (that cleans itself up). Anyway, [from the source](https://github.com/zurb/reveal/blob/master/jquery.reveal.js) it appears that the `reveal:close` event on the element targeted by the plugin can be used - this is the internal mechanism the dialog uses to signal events.

For example:

```
$modal.bind('reveal:close', function () {
    alert("closing started");
});
```

However this event is triggered *before* the animation sequence starts and no event is emitted after the animation/close actually completes.

Such a callback could incorporate a timer (delaying for the same time as the animation) and/or checks on `$modal`'s CSS-visibility, but that's just a hack on an already non-ideal situation - I wouldn't pursue such even if this were my project.

The selector/target for the added "popup" div can also be seen in the source code which can then be used to find and remove it from the DOM. Again, another hack: use a more appropriate/rounded library.

Comment: I'm using the Foundation 5 in my project, that's why i'm trying to use reveal.js too. As you said, and i have to agree with you, they have a scant documentation/flexibility... the only way to do what i want require some kind of hacks... anyway, the ideal situation here may be find a new library that fits my needs